# How to dynamically render strings in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, photoswipe, netlify-cms

I am pulling an array on images from Netlify CMS and passing that to [`vue-picture-swipe`](https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/vue-picture-swipe) component, but the acutal images don't render, even though the path is correct etc.

Not sure what I am doing wrong?

**Template**

```
vue-picture-swipe(:items="items")
```

**Script**

```
    <script>
      export default {
        data: function() {
          return {
                    items: []
                };
        },

            created: function () {
                this.imageList()
            },

            methods: {
                imageList: function () {
                  const files = require.context('~/content/gallery/images/', false, /\.md$/);

                    let images = files.keys().map(key => ({
                        ...files(key)
                    }));

                    let items = images.map(function(value) {
                        return {
                            'src': value.attributes.imgSrc,
                            'thumbnail': value.attributes.imgSrc,
                            'alt': value.attributes.imgDesc
                        }
                    });

                    return this.items = items
                }
            }

        };
    </script>
```

**Rendered HTML**

```
<img src="/assets/uploads/image.jpg" alt="Test Image description" itemprop="thumbnail">
```

Comment: That's a weird looking template. It should look more like this. <vue-picture-swipe :items="items" /> Are you sure you have data in "items"? What happens if you just put {{ items }} in your template? (I'm sure you already tried all this, I'm just making sure)

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Pug. I should have said or just converted back to HTML.

Comment: I don't understand why you require `md` files. Are they not supposed to be images? Is this your real code?

Comment: Netlify CMS stores the image strings in Markdown files. I probably could have left that out for clarity but this is the working code, just not rendering the image.

Comment: What does the DevTools network panel show? Are there `404`s for the image URLs?

Comment: nuxt assets not served from assets. Assets supposed to be bundled by webpack into your app. Only static folder served by nuxt into root

Answer (score 0):

According to your output, if `value.attributes.imgSrc` renders a relative path like `src="/assets/uploads/image.jpg"`, try to require this path.

I'm assuming your "assets" and "components" folders are directly under "src":

```js
let items = images.map(function(value) {
  return {
    'src': require('..' + value.attributes.imgSrc), // or require('@' + value.attributes.imgSrc)
    'thumbnail': require('..' + value.attributes.imgSrc),
    'alt': value.attributes.imgDesc
  }
})
```

---

Note that `vue-picture-swipe` `items` props need `w` and `h` attributes for each item.